# 2.8 - Duplicating in Edit mode isn't working

Tags: rigging, armature, edit-mode

I'm trying to duplicate and move part of an armature in Edit mode, but it isn't duplicating.

1. Go to *Edit mode*
2. Click on the part of the armature that I want to duplicate
3. Press <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> +  <kbd>D</kbd>

And nothing happens, there is no menu pop-up, and moving the armature moves the one that I want to duplicate rather than a copy of it.

I've also tried using the menu to do it, but it gives me the same result.
It can be duplicated in *Object mode*, but then it's the entire armature.

Comment: Hello, that's weird, can you show some screenshots or share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/76cc1cf29018447eb798cf93b2ff12fe

Comment: it seems to work, have you tried with different Blender versions? https://zupimages.net/up/21/29/i2ji.gif

Comment: Thank you for the image! It got me to try clicking the center of the armature bone and duplicate, which worked. For a moment, I thought I'd have to install a new version of Blender.